# Use in-memory database separately for testing - how?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-testing

I have this code:

**my_app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.config["BASE_DIR"] = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///" + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(app.config["BASE_DIR"], "app.db"))

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from user import User

# create all tables
db.create_all()

if not User.query.filter_by(username="test").first():
    dummy_user = User(username="test", password="", email="")
    db.session.add(dummy_user)
    db.session.commit()
```

**user.py:**

```
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin

from my_app import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
```

**tests.py:**

```
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase
from my_app import app, db
from user import User

import os
import unittest


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///:memory:"
        app.config["TESTING"] = True
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    def test_dummy(self):
        assert User.query.count() == 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

How can I make the unit test work?

I want my unit tests to use an in-memory database separate from the main application, but apparently I can not do it the way I'm trying to (by just changing the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI value)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some helpful bits in here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#development-production

Comment: I don't think that's helpful to my problem. I am already defining a different config than the one used for production.

Comment: Do you call `create_app`?

Comment: The problem, I believe, is that you create the `db` from app when you import. Any changes to app after that have no effect. If you split the config and db into 2 files you can first import the app, then change it and last import db from the other module.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the perfect case for inherited configurations!

Have you tried using the template found [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/config.py)? The Config base class contains settings that are common to all your different environments. But you can have a development environment that uses an in-memory database. For example:

```
class Config:
  # pass

class DevConfig(Config):
  SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://path_to_in_memory_db'

class ProductionConfig(Config):
  SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://path_to_production_db'
```

It's also worth looking into using a [factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) to create your app.

Answer (score 2):

I used environment variables to choose the db with pytest.  This works well when using docker-compose to specify a production DB instead of sqllite for dev.

```
# app.py
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATABASE = os.environ.get("DB_URI", f"sqlite:///{os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app.db')}")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = DATABASE
```

And then in test.py inject the DB_URI environment variable to specify a memory db before you import the app or db:

```
import pytest
import os

os.environ['DB_URI'] = "sqlite:///:memory:"
from app import app, db
from models import Model1, Model2


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    client = app.test_client()

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        prepare_data()
    yield client

    db.drop_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a solution or rather a workaround:

I used an environment variable to specify an additional config file to be loaded *before* initializing the db instance.

So I ended up doing this:

```
app.config.from_object("app.config.production")
additional_config = os.environ.get("ADDITIONAL_CONFIG")
if additional_config:
    app.config.from_object(additional_config)
```

in my my_app.py and this in my tests.py:

```
os.environ["ADDITIONAL_CONFIG"] = "app.config.testing"

from my_app import app, db
```

(it is of course important to define the environment variable *before* importing the app object)

Thanks anyway.